# Matlab function signature changes

Tags: matlab

Let us say that I have a Matlab function and I change its signature (i.e. add parameter). As Matlab does not 'compile' is there an easy way to determine which other functions do not use the right signature (i.e. submits the additional parameter). I do not want to determine this at runtime (i.e. get an error message) or have to do text searches. Hope this makes sense. Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: It would be very complicated.

Comment: The functions interact hierarchically. So if I detect a wrong signature call in some function, I will have to change the current function's signature etc. This would snowball into something very complicated. Maybe there is some kind of 'compiler' functionality to check everything.

Comment: @csetzkorn: Matlab has no compiler, only a parser. And that cannot be accessed programatically, so you'll have to bite the bullet I'm afraid....

Comment: @csetzkorn: Just wondering; why would `grep 'myFunc(.*,.*);' *.m` not suffice? (assuming you're on Linux, and this regex accurately captures the "old" function signature)

Comment: @csetzkorn But if yo have to change everything anyway, searches are the most reliable way to do so. Except, if you want to tolerate the old call signature as well, you should use [Rody's method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13581287/296974) with the change to provide the old behaviour on missing parameters.

Comment: Thanks glglgl! The dependency report below might be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more or less what the [dependency report](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2008/02/04/exposing-your-dependencies/) was invented for. Using that tool, you can find what functions/scripts call your altered function. Then it is just a question of manually inspecting every occurrence.

However, I'd advise to make your changes to the function signature such that backwards compatibility is maintained. You can do so by specifying default values for new parameters and/or issuing a `warning` in those scenarios. That way, your code will run, and you will get run-time hints of deprecated code (which is more or less a necessary evil in interpreted/dynamic languages).

For many dynamic languages (and MATLAB specifically) it is generally impossible to fully inspect the code without the interpreter executing the code. Just imagine the following piece of code:

```
x = magic(10);
```

In general, you'd say that the `magic` function is called. However, `magic` could map to a totally different function. This could be done in ways that are invisible to a static analysis tool (such as the dependency report): e.g. `eval('magic = 1:100;');`.

The only way is to go through your whole code base, either inspecting every occurrence manually (which can be found easily with a text search) or by running a test that fully covers your code base.

**edit**:
There is however a way to access intermediate outputs of the MATLAB parser. This can be accessed using the undocumented and unsupported `mtree` function (which can be called like this: `t = mtree(file, '-file');` for every file in your code base). Using the resulting structure you might be able to find calls with a certain amount of parameters.

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising. I guess I am spoiled as I mainly write in higher/compiled languages ...

Comment: +1: wow, I forgot about this one! That's what you get for working on the command line all the time; you forget tools like these exist :)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: the same functionality (minus graphical interface) is contained within the `depfun` command, which can be operated from the CLI.

Comment: @Egon: Yeah, I know, but what I mean that is I use tools like `grep` and `sed` so often on things other than Matlab files that `depfun` is not something that comes to mind first :)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change a function's signature and find all functions/scripts/classes that call it in the "old" way, and change it to the "new" way.

You also indicated you don't want to do it at runtime, or do text searches, but there is no way to detect "incorrect" calls at "parse-time", so I'm afraid these demands leave no option at all to detect old function calls...

What I would do in that case is temporarily add a few lines to the new function:

```
function myFunc(param1, param2, newParam) % <-- the NEW signature

    if nargin == 2
        clc, error('old call detected.'); end
```

and then run the main script/function/whatever in which this function resides. You'll get one error for each time something calls the function incorrectly, along with the error stack in the Matlab command window.

It is then a matter of clicking on the link in the bottom of the error stack, correct the function call, and repeat from the top until no more errors occur.

Don't forget to remove these lines when you're done, or better, replace the word `error` with `warning` just to capture anything that was missed.

Better yet: if you're on linux, a text search would be a matter of

```
$ grep -l 'myFunc(.*,.*); *.m'
```

which will list all the files having the "incorrect" call. That's not too difficult I'd say...You can probably do a similar thing with the standard windows search, but I can't test that right now.

Comment: As they don't want an error message at runtime, I would rather provide the old behaviour in this case.

Comment: @glglgl: Sure, you could issue a warning instead of an error, including the word 'depracated' or so, that would be the better way to go in many contexts. Anyway, as the OP indicated, s/he does not want to do it at runtime and/or issue error messages...so this kind of breaks those rules anyway, but I see no other way to do it.